# Interpolating lines of a Polygon

Tags: line, interpolation, polygon, points, oversampling

Let's suppose we have 5 (x,y) points which makes a closed loop or a polygon. How can I interpolate or upsample some points so that the polygon will have a more round-ish look instead of sharp linear lines between two points? [E.g. see the image. What I have is on the left and what I want is on the right.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6QeNu.png)

A simple MATLAB code is as follows:

```
xv = [0 2 3 2.5 1 0];
yv = [1 0 2 3.5 3.5 1];
plot(xv, yv)
xlim([-1 4])
ylim([-2 5])
```

Comment: You could [have a look at this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/24827/smoothing-polygons-in-contour-map) and apply similar ideas to your polygon.

Comment: You should add a MatLab tag, and also mention it in the subject line.